# what is the opposite of a shoulder screw

Tags: screws, terminology

A shoulder screw's unthreaded section has a bigger diameter than the threaded section. I'm looking for the "opposite" if you'll pardon the term.

What is the name of the screw type where the unthreaded section is just a tad smaller in diameter than the threaded section? The unthreaded section has the same O.D. as the screw at the "valley" of the thread.

Comment: I have seen this in some "self threading" screws, but I do not know if there is a technical name for it.  Tapcon concrete screws are like that for a specific example.

Comment: Called a rolled thread instead of cut.

Comment: With a little more research, "Thread Forming" is the type of screw I was talking about, but still don't think thats a complete answer.

Comment: And often used for cylinder head bolts when dissimilar metals are involved.

Comment: Are we talking about machine screws or structural (wood thread) screws? They're probably named differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called captive screws or captive panel screws.

[image: Socket head captive panel screw]

Comment: there are captive screws of other designs, but this certainly would be the usual application for such a screw.